# Issue while install react-native-firebase/messaging in react native project

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native

I tried using "npm install @react-native-firebase/messaging" in cmd and an issue occured while installing.

While resolving: mealy@0.0.1
Found: react@17.0.2
node_modules/react
react@"17.0.2" from the root project
peer react@"*" from @react-native-firebase/app@11.5.0
node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app
@react-native-firebase/app@"^11.3.3" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer react@"17.0.1" from react-native@0.64.0
node_modules/react-native
react-native@"0.64.0" from the root project
peer react-native@"*" from @react-native-firebase/app@11.5.0
node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app
@react-native-firebase/app@"^11.3.3" from the root project

Answer (score 3):

You need install latest version of `@react-native-firebase/app` and the same version of `@react-native-firebase/analytics`. Because in March this library update depedencies for `react`.

Changes you can see here
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/pull/5042/files

```
npm install @react-native-firebase/app@latest
npm install @react-native-firebase/analytics@latest
```

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you so much.